# How to share the files between gears in scalable drupal in openshift?

Tags: drupal, scale, openshift, haproxy

I would like to have a scalable drupal at openshift. As I know, in a scalable application in openshift, there is a HAproxy cartridge in the head gear, another gear for database. The thing I am not very clear is how the web (code) gears share the files.

The code part are changed when the code commited. Everytime when the code commit with git, the code is duplicated to every web gear. I think openshift will do it automatically and I assume during the commit process, the app is stopped.

How about the user files in the sites/files in drupal. This part is not in the git. I need to copy it to every gears each time when I deploy? If I am wrong, how to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scaling Drupal 7 on Openshift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123586/scaling-drupal-7-on-openshift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related question, [Scaling Drupal 7 on Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123586/scaling-drupal-7-on-openshift), was asked not so long after yours.

You're exactly right that the core Drupal files are copied to each gear with git. But for the remaining user content, the Drupal quickstart [README](https://github.com/openshift/drupal-quickstart/blob/master/README.md:) recommends to use "a background task to copy file contents from gear to gear". I presume they mean an OpenShift cron job, but to me that seems very clunky.

The other suggestion the OP the linked question came across is to point Drupal at S3 for storing and reading user content.